# Calibre not starting under ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, calibre

My calibre is no longer starting and comes up with the following trace:

```
calibre, version 3.21.0
FEHLER: Fehler beim Starten: Es gab einen Fehler beim Starten von calibre. Teile von calibre funktionieren möglicherweise nicht. Für mehr "Details anzeigen" anklicken.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 300, in initialize_db_stage2
    self.start_gui(db)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 233, in start_gui
    main = self.main = Main(self.opts, gui_debug=self.gui_debug)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/ui.py", line 156, in __init__
    ac = self.init_iaction(action)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/ui.py", line 170, in init_iaction
    ac = action.load_actual_plugin(self)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/customize/__init__.py", line 614, in load_actual_plugin
    ac = getattr(importlib.import_module(mod), cls)(gui,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/actions/catalog.py", line 13, in <module>
    from calibre.gui2.tools import generate_catalog
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/tools.py", line 16, in <module>
    from calibre.gui2.convert.single import NoSupportedInputFormats
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/convert/single.py", line 18, in <module>
    from calibre.gui2.convert.look_and_feel import LookAndFeelWidget
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/convert/look_and_feel.py", line 13, in <module>
    from calibre.gui2.convert.look_and_feel_ui import Ui_Form
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/convert/look_and_feel_ui.py", line 286, in <module>
    from calibre.gui2.css_transform_rules import RulesWidget
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/css_transform_rules.py", line 13, in <module>
    from calibre.ebooks.css_transform_rules import (
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/css_transform_rules.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cssutils.css import Property, CSSRule
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils/util.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _fetchgae import _defaultFetcher
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils/_fetchgae.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

Trying to start calibre after this error again runs in a timeout and a message that calibre is already running.
I already tried to reinstall calibre and python, but it does not change the bebaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade libraries:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
pip install --upgrade html5lib
```

Or use Calibre under the Docker:

https://github.com/artiomn/library-docker

Comment: Hi A.N., thank you for your answer!
But in the meantime I installed calibre with the newest version from their website 
https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux 
and it is working fine.
Sorry that I forgot to update my question...